# typoscript assign page:id to plugin attribute

Tags: typo3, typoscript

so all I actually want to do is something like

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.redirectPageLogin = page:id
```

where the page:id is the PID of the current page. replacing 'page:id' with a number works as expected BUT I do need the PID instead of a fixed number. any hints are welcome

Answer (score 1):

redirectPageLogin has to be a single int value:

```
$redirect_url[] = $this->pi_getPageLink(intval($this->conf['redirectPageLogin']));
```

Alternative: use as $redirMethod: getpost or referer
I think that'll fit four you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.redirectPageLogin = TSFE:id
```

or

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.redirectPageLogin = {TSFE:id}
```

or

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.redirectPageLogin.cObject = TEXT
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.redirectPageLogin.cObject.insertData = 1
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.redirectPageLogin.cObject.value = {TSFE:id}
```

Comment: If the property does not have stdWrap, then you are out of luck.

Comment: It seems to be what pgampe says